# Tensorflow (Keras) U-Net Segmentation training fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to train a U-Net with Tensorflow and Keras. Model shown below.

```
def get_unet(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS):
    inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4, up6], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3, up7], axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2, up8], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(32, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1, up9], axis=3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv10])

    #model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-3), loss = [dice_coef_loss], metrics = [dice_coef])
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = [jacard_coef_loss], metrics = [jaccard_distance])
    #model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.summary()

    return model
```

The problem is the training (or maybe the data). The data are jpg images. The masks contain only one class. Because of some small objects I introduced the jaccard_distance. Training is done with:

```
seed = 42
np.random.seed = seed

IMG_WIDTH = 512
IMG_HEIGHT = 512
IMG_CHANNELS = 1

TRAIN_PATH = 'data/train/'
TEST_PATH = 'data/test/'

train_ids = next(os.walk(TRAIN_PATH))[1]
test_ids = next(os.walk(TEST_PATH))[1]

X_train = np.zeros((len(train_ids), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS), dtype=np.float32)
Y_train = np.zeros((len(train_ids), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.float32)

print('Resizing training images and masks')
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(train_ids), total=len(train_ids)):
    path = TRAIN_PATH + id_
    print(path)
    img = imread(path + '/images/' + id_ + '.jpg', as_gray=True)
    img = img/255
    img = img[:, :, newaxis]
    img = resize(img, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)
    X_train[n] = img
    mask = np.zeros((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.float32)
    for mask_file in next(os.walk(path + '/masks/'))[2]:
        mask_ = imread(path + '/masks/' + mask_file, as_gray=True)
        mask_ = np.expand_dims(resize(mask_, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant',preserve_range=True), axis=-1)
        mask = np.maximum(mask, mask_)

    Y_train[n] = mask

print('Done!')

model = get_unet_middle(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS)

################################

callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5, monitor='val_loss'),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model_for_leak_middle.h5', verbose=1, monitor='val_loss', save_freq='epoch', save_best_only=True)]
results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=4, epochs=50, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Because of using jaccard_distance I use `np.float32` as data type for `X_train` and `Y_train`.
After some epochs of decreasing the loss, suddenly the loss and jaccard_distance changes their values.

```
Train on 180 samples, validate on 21 samples
...
Epoch 20/50
176/180 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6334 - jaccard_distance: 63.7578
Epoch 00020: val_loss improved from 0.14278 to 0.14249, saving model to model_for_leak_middle.h5
180/180 [==============================] - 47s 260ms/sample - loss: 0.6345 - jaccard_distance: 63.6719 - val_loss: 0.1425 - val_jaccard_distance: 82.2346
Epoch 21/50
176/180 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6041 - jaccard_distance: 63.4807
Epoch 00021: val_loss improved from 0.14249 to 0.14220, saving model to model_for_leak_middle.h5
180/180 [==============================] - 47s 260ms/sample - loss: 0.6041 - jaccard_distance: 63.7875 - val_loss: 0.1422 - val_jaccard_distance: 82.2784
Epoch 22/50
176/180 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5860 - jaccard_distance: 63.4502
Epoch 00022: val_loss did not improve from 0.14220
180/180 [==============================] - 47s 259ms/sample - loss: 0.6741 - jaccard_distance: 54.1866 - val_loss: 0.3247 - val_jaccard_distance: 44.9204
```

After finishing training the history looks like...
[image]

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may work on hyperparameter tuning, for example you may reduce the dropout to 0.1 or 0.2.
I think also the size of your dataset may affect the results.
If you had improvement please share with us. I am interested too to know how thing are resolved.
All the best

Answer (score 0):

I would say your model learned how to validate very well, because it has a small amount of validation samples, so it learned the validation parameters and pratically ignored the training samples.